# After redirecting to another state using ui-router success/failure of old requests still launch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, angular-ui-router

I have web page created using angular with ui-router. Generally it works well, I have only one problem.

I have one view that makes a lot of separate calls to different web servers. If any of those web servers returns 401 I want to redirect user to login page. All servers have SSO, so user has to login only once.

Sample code for those requests is as follows:

```
request.success(function(data) {
        //Do something
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        errorService.basicErrorHandler(request.url, data, status, headers, config);
});
```

and basicErrorHandler does that(only relevant part):

```
if (status === 401 || status === 403) {
    $location.path('/login');
}
```

Now what sometimes happens:

- user is redirected to /login by one of the request from /secured-page
- user decides not to log in, and goes to some part of page that doesn't require authentication, say /landing-page
- one of the requests made by /secured-page comes back now, because one of servers was very slow in delivering the result. It also gets 401, so user gets redirected to /login page again

In ng-router in the case above the user wouldn't be redirected again by a request started in /secured-page, after redirect was already made. How can I avoid this behavior in ui-router?

Comment: What the errorService.basicErrorHandler function is doing?

Comment: As I wrote in my question:

    if (status === 401 || status === 403) {
        $location.path('/login');
    }

It does other things on status 404(which doesn't happen, because I don't get 404's), plus it logs things with $log.